# how to show content on button click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So far I have tried this, but it is not working. If I change the footer to div in this Line `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");` than it show all the div in my code,I also do not want this.

**Can anyone help me by telling what is wrong in this code and how to make this code working ?**

**HTML**

```
<p> name:</p> <div> john</div>
<p> class: </p> <div> English</div>
<p> email: </p> <div> some@gmail.com</div>
<footer>
    <button onclick="show()">Contact</button>
    <p id="first"></p>
    <p id="second"></p>
    <p id="third"></p>
</footer>
```

**JS**

```
function show() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML =
    'first div: ' + x[0].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML =
    'second div: ' + x[1].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML =
    'third div: ' + x[2].innerHTML;
    }
```

Comment: Can you put some `class` or `id` to your divs? Otherwise all divs will be returned using this code - `document.getElementsByTagName("div");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors:

You have only one footer, I guess you want to get the content of all divs.
Your id's are wrong, "firstHere" doesn't exists, but "first" does, same for the second and third ids.

UPDATE: You can add a class to your divs (if you have another divs in the page but you want to ignore them).

To get several elements, you can also use **querySelectorAll**, using a css selector as argument.

Try this:

```js
function show() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".your-class");
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML =
    'first div: ' + x[0].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML =
    'second div: ' + x[1].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML =
    'third div: ' + x[2].innerHTML;
    }
```

```html
<p> name:</p> <div class="your-class"> john</div>
<p> class: </p> <div class="your-class"> English</div>
<p> email: </p> <div class="your-class"> some@gmail.com</div>
<footer>
    <button onclick="show()">Contact</button>
    <p id="first"></p>
    <p id="second"></p>
    <p id="third"></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I have also tried this, I do not want this because I have other div in my code too.

Comment: Then add a class to your divs

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `document.getElementById` need to be the same than your id in the html

Here how to do this:

```
function show() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML =
    'first div: ' + x[0].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML =
    'second div: ' + x[1].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML =
    'third div: ' + x[2].innerHTML;
}
```

Here the manual for [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Yes, the id were not same. I have updated the question. Using div cause problems because I have other div in my code too, how to handle this ?